# Pandas series np.max with NaN does not show NaN as max value unlike numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

data_df["colname"]

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

0     -475.0
1     -799.0
2     -656.0
3     -444.0
4     -901.0
       ...
575      NaN
576      NaN
577      NaN
578      NaN
579      NaN


type(data_df["colname"].iloc[579])
<class 'numpy.float64'>

data_df["colname"].iloc[579] 
nan
```

When I run normal array with np.nan I get the followings:

```
>>> np.max([1,2,3,4,np.float64(np.nan)], initial=1)
nan

>>> np.max([1,2,3,4,np.nan], initial=1)
nan
```

But with pandas, despite containing the NaN value:

```
np.max(data_df["colname"]) 
83.0
```

It does not match, what is going on here?

---

Furthermore although np.amax has 'initial' argument:

```
>>> np.max([1,2,3,4,np.nan], initial=1)
nan
```

pandas it gives an error:

```
np.max(data_df["colname"], initial=1)


    validate_kwargs(fname, kwargs, self.defaults)
  File "/Users/-/poetry/virtualenvs/-/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py", line 153, in validate_kwargs
    _check_for_invalid_keys(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
  File "/Users/-/poetry/virtualenvs/-/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py", line 127, in _check_for_invalid_keys
    raise TypeError(f"{fname}() got an unexpected keyword argument '{bad_arg}'")
TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
```

seems like it does not pass pandas keyword argument validation.

Comment: I think `np.max` actually delegates the task to the pandas Series `.max` method.  Check its docs.  That has `skipna` parameter

Comment: Notice your error traceback actually raises the error in `pandas` code.  The `initial` verification has been passed on to `pandas`.  `np.max(data_df['colname'].values, initial=1)` is the `pure` numpy version.

Comment: @hpaulj you answered my question, should you post your comment as an answer i will accept it as the solution.

Comment: though it is quite puzzling why both implementations differs so much like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice your error traceback actually raises the error in `pandas` code. The initial verification has been passed on to `pandas`.

```
 np.max(data_df['colname'].values, initial=1)
```

is the pure numpy version.

(I may add details later.)

Think of `np.max` as the original version that behaves like other `numpy` `ufunc`.  `np.nanmax` is one of a number of add ons in the `nanfunctions.py`.  Here it replaces `nan` with `-inf`.  And only works with floats.  `pandas` users encounter missing data more, so its developers have added bells-n-whistles, The extra `nan` handling does cost time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `np.nanmax()` funtion it fixes the problem:

```py
import numpy as np

np.nanmax([1,2,3,4,np.nan])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4.0
```

Also you can use this solution for pandas DataFrames too:

```py
import numpy as np

np.nanmax(data_df["colname"].values)
```